# Why is the updated value of 'nums1' not being used at the end of the function?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm faced with this situation. I have a function that takes in a list[int] 'nums1' and the objective is to merge its content with the content of nums2 based on some criteria. That part is being completed within the else component of the if else statement shown in the following snipper, however once I perform the sort(), it appears as though the value being used is the raw input of the nums1 rather than the updated value from the else block. I thought that the updates would be in range as far as scope for the sort call but perhaps not?

I print the value of nums1 after the if else block and it outputs the expected value for nums1, but once the function completes it reverts to detecting nums1 with the input value.

```
def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """
    if m + n == m:
        nums1 = nums2 if m == 0 else nums1
    else:
        nums1 = nums1[:m]
        nums1.extend(nums2)


    print('nums1', nums1)
    print('nums2', nums2)
    nums1.sort()
```

Comment: This code does not do anything after the sort call.  So if nums1 is being printed after the sort, it must happen in some other code that you have not shown us.  Please show us the **whole** code.

Comment: this looks like a method of a class ?  what is the rest of the class...

Comment: also, `List` is not defined.  did you mean `list` ?

Comment: However, I can make a guess.  This code contains `nums1 = ...`, which **reassigns** nums1 as a brand-new local variable, which means it no longer refers to the same variable which was passed as a parameter.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's actually a leetcode question. Here's the link. I was not provided more Than the class with the method. https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150

Comment: @JohnGordon I was beginning to suspect something along those lines. I figured that because nums1 is already in scope of the if/else block that it would just assign it the new value? So how do I access the changes from out the block also? Perhaps name it something else within the if/else?

Comment: If you want to modify the original input list, you can't use `nums1 = ...`.  Instead you have to use methods that modify the list contents in-place, such as `.remove()`, `.append()`, and `.extend()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon ahh thank you that makes sense. I'll update shortly.

Comment: @JohnGordon Posted the working code below. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code works nicely.

the `merge()` function that answers the question is in the middle.

basically, it reads the 2 lists and slices them to their index (m, n) respectively.

then it joins them and does a sort.

i also removed the `self` argument since that is usually the convention for a class, which is not required here.

At least, that is what the question in the comments asks for.

```py
def main():
    ''' main entry point for the code '''
    nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
    nums2 = [2,5,6]
    m, n = 3, 3

    result = merge(nums1, m, nums2, n)
    print(result)


def merge(nums1: list[int], m: int, nums2: list[int], n: int):
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """
    # create a new list
    new_list = nums1[:m] + nums2[:n]
    new_list = sorted(new_list)
    return new_list


# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @JohnGordon for pointing me in the right direction. Here's the finished code:

```
 def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """

    if m + n == m:
        nums1.extend(nums2) if m == 0 else nums1
    else:
        del(nums1[m:])
        nums1.extend(nums2)


    nums1.sort()
```

Comment: why bother checking for this condition `m + n == m` ?

Comment: You could write the `else` branch more simply as `nums1[m:] = nums2`